# Storing NFT metadata on IPFS with BaseURI, can I update the JSON dynamically for tokens when they are minted?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, ipfs, nft, openzeppelin

I'm trying to create a collection of 10,000 (ERC-721) tokens, whose metadata are stored on IPFS.
Each image associated to a token would be uploaded on IPFS beforehand with its unique CDI.

Since tokens will not be minted all at once, at first I want each metadata json to be empty and link to a placeholder image.

**My question is**: without setting specific TokenURI in my contract (which I want to avoid), how can I change the json file associated with a token when it's minted, without changing the BaseURI which must be common for all tokens?

This is how it should work:

```
ipfs://Qx000000000000000000/1.json  // json file points to nothing
// token 1 is minted
ipfs://Qx000000000000000000/1.json  // json file is updated but keeps the same ipfs base URI
```

I guess it should involve IPNS, but I can't find a specific guide on the best practice for this. Although I see this method is used all the time, for example even by the Bored Ape Yacht Club collection.